# How to use onPause with Android?

Tags: android

using `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle ..) and onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle ..)`
was really good and work, but it is working when click Turn off button on Emulator.
Now, i want to save state and restore the saved data when below button used:
[image: Emulator]

I think it is possible to use OnPause() OR oOnStop(), if i am right, How to use it,
it will be enough to show me Java source of saving one boolean variable, and restore it,
Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would use `onPause()`, as `onStop()` is not guaranteed to be called.  See the [application fundamentals](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html) for details on the lifecycle.

To save and restore a boolean, I would use `SharedPreferences`.  There is a code example on the [data storage page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) that shows how to save and restore a boolean.  They use `onCreate()` and `onStop()`, but I would use `onResume()` and `onPause()`, for the reasons I have already mentioned.

Answer (score 13):

I had problems reading `sharedPreferences` after PowerOff when  they were stored using `onPause`. The workaround was to call `clear()` first.

```
   public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";

   protected void onPause(){
        super.onPause();

        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        // Necessary to clear first if we save preferences onPause. 
        editor.clear();
        editor.putInt("Metric", mMetric);
        editor.commit();
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

the example :

```
public class Calc extends Activity {
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle state){
   super.onCreate(state);
   . . .

   // Restore preferences
   SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
   boolean silent = settings.getBoolean("silentMode", false);
   setSilent(silent);
}

@Override
protected void onStop(){
   super.onStop();

  // We need an Editor object to make preference changes.
  // All objects are from android.context.Context
  SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
  editor.putBoolean("silentMode", mSilentMode);

  // Commit the edits!
  editor.commit();
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

See Step 7 and Step 8 in [the Android SDK notepad tutorial part 3.](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/notepad-ex3.html) for an example saving the state to a sqlite DB (using a previously defined db-helper class.)

Answer (score 0):

In that case you have no other option than [making your state persistant in one of the ways described in Android DevGuide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)

Answer (score 0):

you can just override onPause() in your activity say activtyA when you are navigating to another activity say activityB and override onResume() when u come back to the activityA.